# TryParseExact() method not parsing dates selected from jQuery's datepicker

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datepicker

I am using jQuery's *`datepicker`* widget in the following way(in my **Master Page**) :

```
<script>
   $(".datepicker").datepicker({
                    showAnim: 'fadeIn',
                    minDate: 0,
                    maxDate: "3M",
                    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"                    
                });
 </script>
```

I have a `asp:Repeater` Control in my **Content Page**.In the C# code(of my **Content Page**), I am using the `DateTime.TryParseExact` method to get the date from the repeater control and parse it , in the following way :

```
for (int i = 0; i < rptr.Items.Count; i++)
 {
....
...//find other controls
...
      TextBox txtDate = (TextBox)rptr.Items[i].FindControl("txtServiceDate");

   DateTime eventDate = new DateTime();

            if (txtDate.Text != null)
            {
                if (DateTime.TryParseExact(txtDate.Text, "dd-mm-yy", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out eventDate))
                {
                    cartObj.ServiceDate = eventDate; //code doesn't go here
                }
                else
                {
                    cartObj.ServiceDate = DateTime.Now; //code reaches here!which means parsing failed
                }
            }
            else
            {
                cartObj.ServiceDate = DateTime.Now;
            }
...
....

...//other code
}
```

As you can see in `datepicker()`, i have specified the date-format as `dd-mm-yy', but this date doesn't get formatted in my`TrParseExact()` method even though the formats sepcified are the same.

What could possibly be wrong ?

**EDIT:** 
I have added a screenshot of what goes into the TryParseExact method in debug mode  :

[image]

Comment: `mm` means minutes in .NET custom format strings, not months... (I'd also *strongly* recommend using yyyy rather than yy... and ideally yyyy-MM-dd instead of the other way round... that way it's the ISO-8601 format.)

Comment: @JonSkeet :  i was using `yyyy-MM-dd` format . But this did not get parsed too and i guess i can't use the same format in `datepicker()` as it does not produce required date format.

Comment: Well then cut out the jQuery part by giving a sample of a value which can't be parsed, and hard-coding that into a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: are u suggesting i remove the *dateFormat* option from the datepicker() ??

Comment: No, I'm suggesting that you pick an appropriate format (yyyy-MM-dd) and separate out the jQuery part from the ASP.NET part: you can tackle the two problems in either order, but basically you want to make sure you can format the date appropriate in jQuery, and you want to make sure you can parse the date appropriately in ASP.NET. Currently, we don't know which bit is causing the problem - possibly both. Separate them.

Comment: I am parsing the date because i have specified the data type as `DateTime` in my DB. I guess changing that to string , will solve my problem as the datepicker is displaying the date in proper format as I need. Is this the best alternative ?

Comment: No, don't change your database. Just work out where the problem is - find out what jQuery is *actually* sending, and work on getting that bit right. Once that's right, work on making sure you can parse that value. Or do it the other way round - the two tasks are entirely independent, once you've decided which format you're actually going to use.]

Comment: jquery is sending the date in : dd/MM/yyyy format . And while entering the `TryParseExact()` method . This date only goes into that line of code.

Comment: Okay, in that case you should clearly *parse* it in that format as well... or see whether you can change the jQuery datePicker configuration to format it differently. If it's *guaranteed* to use dd/MM/yyyy then you might as well just stick with that - but you'll need to parse it appropriately.#

Comment: Please see the screenshot i have added in my question of what goes into the TryParseExact() method in debug mode . Does everything look alright?

Comment: Not quite, because you're passing in `null` as the IFormatProvider. It would be better to parse in `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`. But apart from that, the screenshot looks okay - but isn't the code shown in the rest of the question. If that still doesn't work after you've changed to use the invariant culture, I suggest you try to isolate the behaviour in a short but *complete* example, ideally as a console app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74228/discussion-between-abhishek-ghosh-and-jon-skeet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All credit goes to ***@Jon Skeet*** . In the `TryParseExact()` method I was passing `null`as a value to the `IFormatProvider`. Passing the culture information in it , did the magic.

I changed the `IFormatProvider`'s value to `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` which is in the `System.Globalization` namespace.

**The `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` property is used when you aren't sure ahead of time, what culture format your dates and decimal / currency values will be in.**

Following is the method I am using now :

```
 if (DateTime.TryParseExact(txtDate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture , System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out eventDate))
   {
      //date parsed successfully . Do something with it !
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to format your date as follows:

`dd-mm-yy`

`[day]-[minute]-[year]`

In .NET, months are represented as `MM`.

You can find a full reference for all string representations of dates here
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In C#, mm means minutes. Try using MM, as in:

```
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(txtDate.Text, "dd-MM-yy", etc etc etc
```